# FileZilla: Can upload to directory from one computer but not another

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, ftp, lamp, filenames

I am having issues uploading a file to a particular directory on my site (LAMP). The directories permissions are 777. The odd thing is it works fine on one machine (same file) but not on a another.

The only difference is the one that doesnt work is a Mac and the one that does work is a PC.

The error message I get is:

`553 Can't open that file: Permission denied`

Would anyone know why this is?

Both computers are using the same credentials

Comment: uploading same file?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor yes and yes

Comment: what is the file path in Mac ? is the current Mac user an Administrator account ?